# Why does CSS selector returns an array of elements?

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, jquery

I am writing very basic html and wanted to select only one element using css selector. However, the query returns one element in an array. I can access my element by indexing the array with [0] but is there a way to modify the query to return my element only?

```
<input class='myInput' id='myId'>
```

Css Selector:

```
'input.myInput'
```

When used in Chrome dev console, I see:

```
[<input class='myInput' id='myId'>]
```

instead of:

```
<input class='myInput' id='myId'>
```

Comment: Should this be tagged jQuery too?

Comment: @BjornJohnson: I dunno. It's not clear whether he's using the native API or jQuery to select elements.

Comment: Yeah.  I was more or less asking him.  I should have just said "Are you using jQuery?" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`querySelector()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#queryselector) method, which always returns the first element from a query:

```
var element = document.querySelector('input.myInput');
```

jQuery doesn't have a direct equivalent so you have to use the `[0]` index for that.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery returns queries with a jQuery Object, which is an array of the returned objects. So to get the line that you are looking for `<input class="myInput" id="myId">` what you need to do is `$('input.myInput')[0];` which gets the 0th element in the array, in this case there is only one, but to get the HTML element you need the `[0]` after the selector query.

Just an FYI on ther ways to get the same input:

```
$('.myInput')[0];
$('#myId')[0];
$('input')[0];
```

Or any of the above selectors with `.first()` after instead of `[0]` because they both grab the first element in the returned jQuery Object.